# Importing nested module in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import a python module A in a notebook.

The module A is part of a package P and inside A another module B also part of P is called

```
Package_P
---- __init__.py
---- A.py
-------- import B
---- B.py

Notebook_folder
---- X.ipynb
-------- import A
```

I am getting the following error in the notebook when trying to import A:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'B'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to how relative import works in Python. You could fix it by modifying path variable in the notebook:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
```